Why is it said to be alias free in such a multirate system?
Page 246 in multirate systems and filter banks by P. P. Vaidyanathanm.

The sampling in the first stage should have brought the aliases already, why does the author claim that it is an aliaa-free system?
S(z^M) should be a function of z^M, which cannot mitigate the aliases, for example, s(z^M)=z^M or even s(z^M)=1.
The full book is here: https://authors.library.caltech.edu/records/rmhds-22q28

I don't have that book, but that the aliases cancel is exactly the point of polyphase-decomposed multirate systems; at that point this figure, the polyphase resampler should have been explained in the book or is about to be introduced. The fdact that the sentence starts with "So the system is alias free" indicates the explanation for why is just in the paragraph before. Could you show that paragraph and maybe ask your question based on what you understood and didn't understand about that paragraph?

Hi Marcus, I have pasted the link for the full book.

thanks! but can you ask your question based on what you understood and didn't understand about that previous paragraph, and actually add the paragraph? I'm sorry, but I won't be able to download a lot of chapters looking for your figure and your text on the fly.

Just in Chapter 5.

That are 98 pages. I need you to spell out what you did and did not understand about that chapter. Section 5.7, to quote the chapter outline "develops the general theory of alias-free systems"; so, yeah, I'd honestly refer you to that chapter. We can help explain what you don't understand about it, but we cannot inherently know what you don't understand. Also, our explanations will probably not be shorter and not necessarily easier to read than the book that you're already working with.

I don't understand why the author claims that "So the system is alias free", and I think the aliases are there.

The final result is alias free. The aliases are there in each individual path. The addition of the paths leads to constructive cancellation where we need to not have aliases, as well as using them to recreate the higher frequency components properly again. I gave a detailed example in my answer here of how this same effect happens in the computation of the DFT (with down-sampling and reconstruction) which is very similar.  I hope that is helpful!

OP has also posted this at https://www.dsprelated.com/thread/17196/why-is-it-said-to-be-alias-free-in-such-a-multirate-system in case other helpful answers appear there as well. Here is my response from there:
The phase of the aliases rotates after each delay prior to the down-samplers, and then again after the up-samplers in each of the recreated Nyquist zones. Due to this rotation that is proportional to frequency (a delay of one sample in the time domain is a linear phase in frequency from 0 to -2pi for the frequency from DC to the sampling rate), we get perfect cancellation of all aliases except in the region where the signal originally started. It's a worthwhile exercise to try it yourself with M=2 with two tones (one that would alias) so that you can see for yourself how that works. The purpose of this is to demonstrate how poly-phase decomposition works.
---- adding to the above here:
Very similar to this is my "Sampling View of the FFT" which also answers how the decimation in the FFT does not lead to destructive aliasing even though aliasing temporarily occurs:
The "Decimate in Time" FFT is based on decimating the time domain samples into even and odd samples, and then computing two FFT's of length $N/2$ instead of one FFT of length $N$, resulting in a significant processing savings (so it will keep doing this down until we have a bunch of $N=2$ FFT's, but we can consider the first decimation to see how the interesting aliasing effect similar to the OP's case here.
Decimating the input samples into even and odd samples so that we have two buffers of time domain samples each at half the total length is identical to inserting a $z^{+1}$ in one of the samples prior to decimate by two. (A $z^{-1}$ is a delay in time of one sample, so $z^{+1}$ is a non-causal advance in time of one sample. Since the FFT is post processing on a buffer of data, this non-causal aspect is of no consequence and just used for proper time alignment:

Next we consider a spectrum of a sampled (discrete-time) signal where I created both a low frequency signal (in red) and high frequency signal (in blue). High frequency meaning up near Nyquist or $f_s/2$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate. The graphic also shows all the common ways we represent the frequency domain over the unique spectrum range from DC to the sampling rate.

The "advance" in time of one sample has a positive linear phase response in the frequency domain going from $0$ at DC up to $2\pi$ at $f_s$. Prior to decimating by two, observe how the two spectrums would compare for our even and odd samples:

In particular observe how the two two spectrums right at Nyquist will be exactly out of phase, but the spectrum at DC and at $f_s$ will be exactly in phase.
To understand the next step requires an understanding of how aliasing occurs when a signal is decimated (or equivalently when an analog signal is sampled - decimating is just resampling). What you see, as a quick explanation, is that the input spectrum at the new sampling rate will replicate at every multiple of the new sampling rate (periodicity in the frequency domain for a discrete-time signal: the spectrum from DC to the sampling rate must repeat in every higher multiple of $Nf_s$ to $(N+1)f_s$, leading to the aliasing as presented here (best explanation I can give in a paragraph, further study of sampling and aliasing may be needed to really get this):

When we decimate by two we alias the input spectrums, one of the two spectrums was phase rotated as demonstrated earlier. This leads the following relationships between the output spectrums after decimation:

So here comes the magic- The reconstruction in the FFT in how the two smaller FFTs (represented by the spectrums above) are combined.  For the low frequency half of the final FFT result, those two spectrums are simply summed, which cancels out the aliasing completely! Further, for the high frequency half of the final FFT result, those same two spectrums are subtracted, after adding a $z^{-1}$ delay to one of the paths as depicted below and perfectly reconstructing the upper frequency half from the aliases!


Hi Dan, thank you very much! What if the incoming signal is not a discrete-time x[n] but a continuous-time x(t) instead? Would the down-sampling cause the aliases?

Creating the same system for a continuous time input would also need a continuous time output, and for that an infinite number of delays that are each infinitely short.  The aliasing occurs in down-sampling for discrete or continuous time. It's the reconstruction that creatively cancels the aliasing.

So the shorter answer to your new question is the block diagram cannot be applied to a continuous time signal for any practical implementation. The signal provided to the input is from an A/D that has already been guaranteed to not have aliasing (with proper anti-alias filter in the analog).  After that, the resulting diagram will process the signal with no aliasing distortion at the final output.

Thanks, Dan. Is it possible to take the up-sampling first and then the down-sampling to mitigate the aliases if the incoming signal is a continous-time x(t)?

@user71925  If the incoming signal is continuous and you only have 1 ADC, then you're only hope is the anti-alias filter. If you have two, you can synthesize a 2x sampling rate and it would be equivalent to that and relax the filter (but timing is tricky in the analog domain). Ongoing discussion is discouraged in the comments (it will soon flag the moderators and I've been scolded before!). Did I answer your primary question as you posted it? I'm happy to go into a chat room with you for further discussion when I have some more time.
